# VNC accessible headless ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, headless

I want to have a VNC access with my linux ubuntu server 16.04 LTS dedicated machine but I don't want to install any xfce, gnome or any kind of graphic interface(no desktop, no gui) I just want to have a VNC access looking on a terminal.

I want something exactly like this and how can this be possible? https://www.screencast.com/t/enlMYGVYH6nG

I have already tried this:

https://lxtreme.nl/blog/headless-x11/

but I got an error:

```
X -configure
    X.Org X Server 1.18.4
    Release Date: 2016-07-19
    X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
    Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
    Current Operating System: Linux outdoreality 4.4.0-101-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 18:29:59 UTC 2017 x86_64
    Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic root=UUID=5e9dcfe3-3311-42de-ad56-4ab5f3d98f11 ro
    Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:57:05PM
    xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
    Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
    Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
    (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Nov 27 15:18:04 2017
    List of video drivers:
        dummy
        modesetting
    No devices to configure.  Configuration failed.
```

I'm experimenting things first with my virtualbox before implementing it on my dedicated server. Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you try running VNC's X server?

Comment: VNC is made for GUI. if you just want CLI access, you'd be better off with `ssh`.

Comment: use plain old SSH to access your server. no need to bloat your server with unneeded VNC library just to get a terminal

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  can you tell me how to do it? any tutorial will help ;)

Comment: What executables that start with "X" are available on your system? In your software repos?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams well the system is headless no X available, just the x11vnc

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sorry please clarify, what command i need to execute so i can get what are you looking for?